# dbpedia sparql to get all career info for all soccer players of a particular nationality

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to make the perfect sparql query from dbpedia in order to get career information for all soccer players of a particular country of birth, like so :

```
birthCountry | player | birthDate | year | team | matches | goals
```

For now I managed to do this query which does not fulfill my needs

```
select ?birthCountry ?player ?birthDate ?year ?team ?matches ?goals where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ; 
            dbo:birthPlace/dbo:country ?birthCountry ;
            dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
            dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:years ?year ;
           dbo:team/rdfs:label ?team ;
           dbo:numberOfMatches ?matches ;
           dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals .
  filter (langMatches(lang(?team), "EN"))
  filter (?birthCountry in (dbr:England))
}
order by ?player ?year
```

The problem is I get duplicates, due to some birth date formating that I don't understand :

```
birthCountry    | player            | birthDate              | year              | team                     | matches | goals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:England [http] | :AJ_George [http] | "1996-12-06"^^xsd:date | "2014"^^xsd:gYear | "Banbury United F.C."@en | 4       | 0
:England [http] | :AJ_George [http] | "1996-12-6"^^xsd:date  | "2014"^^xsd:gYear | "Banbury United F.C."@en | 4       | 0
:England [http] | :AJ_George [http] | "1996-12-06"^^xsd:date | "2014"^^xsd:gYear | "Oxford United F.C."@en  | 2       | 0
:England [http] | :AJ_George [http] | "1996-12-6"^^xsd:date  | "2014"^^xsd:gYear | "Oxford United F.C."@en  | 2       | 0
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: what is the purpose of `group by` here given the fact that you don't use any aggregate function? you have to use `sum` on the matches and goals. if you don't want this you don't need the group by

Comment: nationality can be achieved to some extent by using the country of the players birthplace. `?player dbo:birthPlace ?place . ?place a dbo:Country` - But as I said it's limited and there is also a dedicated property for the nationality but not for all people

Comment: career year and team name are both attached to the career station. `dbo:team` and `dbo:years` are the properties to use here

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! Now it is better but since cannot handle filter and display the name of the team

Comment: what is the "name of the team"? I mean, you have the team already. you could get the `rdfs:label` of `?team` if you want the human readable string.

Comment: country filter is using the URI of a country,  like `dbo:birthPlace dbr:England` for example. But again, this is not always the nationality and it depends on the data, i.e. for birth place a triple mapping to the country has to be in the dataset.